# override CSS for a flat UI style

Tags: javascript, css, overriding

I have to override a background color of a CSS class from #1abc9c to steelgreen.

My html control is

```
<select id="Users" title="App. Users" data-toggle="select" class="form-control select select-primary"></select>
```

The original version in flat-ui.min.js

```
.select2-drop .select2-highlighted > .select2-result-label {
        color: #fff;
        background: #1abc9c;
    }
```

I am trying to override the background color as,

```
$(".select2-drop").css('background', 'steelblue !important');
$(".select2-highlighted").css('background', 'steelblue !important');
$(".select2-result-label").css('background', 'steelblue !important');
$(".select2-drop .select2-highlighted > .select2-result-label").css('background', 'steelblue !important');
```

None of them are worked out. I also tried by removing the `!important` but no luck.

Pl. let me know what am I missing here!

Comment: Is there any reason your using jQuery to change the colors instead of CSS?

Comment: @Jamie: Not certainly. If it can be fixed using CSS, I would be more happy to implement!

Comment: Can you provide a link to your code?

Comment: I don't have it in a fiddler but I just updated the question with the html syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new color class:

```
.select2-drop .select2-highlighted > .select2-result-label.newcolorclass{ color: new_color;}
```

Fill new_color with whatever you want.

to change all select2-result-label class to the new color:

```
var j = document.querySelectorAll('.select2-result-label');
for (var i=0;i<j.length;i++){
    j[i].className = j[i].className.replace('select2-result-label','select2-result-label newcolorclass');
}
```

to reset all select2-result-label class to the original color:

```
var j = document.querySelectorAll('.newcolorclass');
for (var i=0;i<j.length;i++){
    j[i].className = j[i].className.replace('newcolorclass','');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `background-color: steelblue !important;` instead of using `background: steelblue !important;`?

The `background` CSS property is a shorthand property that allows you to set multiple background-related properties in one declaration. Since `background-color` is a more specific CSS property, and coupled with the `!important` declaration, you should have better luck overriding the color.

If you are still having no luck I recommend using the dev tools in a web browser (Chrome is my preference, but FF and IE11 both have decent ones too) to verify the CSS rule that is truly setting your control's background color and possibly get a glimpse as to why your override is not being used. I have been burned by CSS precedence in the past when trying to override framework styles and the dev tools have helped me trace through why a particular rule is followed and others are not.

Also, I agree with @jamie-buttons-coulter, that unless there is a specific reason to make the override using jQuery/JavaScript you should instead implement it using CSS (either in a local style block or an imported css file, whichever is consistent with the rest of your project).